# Can I train and serve a Google Cloud ML model on a specific GCP network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

We are currently evaluating ml-engine and the infrastructure team are asking about security.

Is it possible to train and serve predictions on a specific network (for example using Firewall rules so that online predictions are only accessible from specific IPs)?

e.g.

`gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training <...> --network internal_VPN_only`

or

`gcloud ml-engine models create <...> --network internal_VPN_only`

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible yet, be we're working on it. If you're open to a discussion, please reach out to us @ cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: Brilliant, thank you and very happy to hear you are working on it. When we get to production, we will definitely be in touch and I can feed back to the rest of the team.

Comment: I've +1'd the feature request on our end.